# What is the fluid clearance rate inside the retina?

Tags: human-eye

I'm attempting to model the chemical concentration between several compartments of the eye, including the retina. Does anyone have any idea what the rate of fluid removal is in the retina, or could direct me to a study of this?

EDIT: It appears that Müller cells play a crucial role in this, dehydrating the retinal tissue. I am attempting to find the rate at which they achieve this. (see link)
http://retinatoday.com/2008/11/1108_07.php/

Comment: For the best of my knowledge the structure that dehydrate the retina is Retinal Pigment Epithelium, not Muller cells.

Comment: look at the answer, do you need subsequent clarification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the RPE (retinal pigment epithelium) is in charge of absorbing the "water" from the retina and beneath it.

> Water [is eliminated from subretinal space](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-ii-anatomy-and-physiology-of-the-retina/the-retinal-pigment-epithelium/) by active transport by the
>   RPE. The transportation rate was estimated to range from 1.4 to 11 µl
>   x cm-2 x h-1.

Comment: Oh you are fantastic! Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Freeman You are always welcome %)